# Picture content control - Word 2013

Tags: microsoft-word, pictures

I would like to control a content of picture in built form. Actually I got stuck on this problem. When I set a placeholder for picture and user will choose picture `A` it is resized to abnormal size. It looks so small. I cannot find some solution how to **set default** size of inserted picture.

I tried to built a quick part with image but eventually I cannot merge a picture content control into quick part. I also tried to set a absolute size to placeholder but it does not work after inserted picture, it is warped again.

I got more pictures so I would like to set each size for image.

My goal in **brief**: Set absolute sizes (probably to placeholder) of inserted pictures.

Anyone can help please?

Answer (score 0):

I found soluntion.

I set a table-cell a fill in this cell with picture.

```
1. Make table-cell
2. Right click > table prop
3. In Row set height is **EXACTLY** (set height whatever you want)
4. Tick in tab Column "Preferred width" and set your width
5. Insert picture
```

PS: Default wrapping text next to picture needs to be set on "In line with text"